# onChange event on two web pages

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, web, onchange

I hava a two web pages. One is main.php and other is combo.php. combo.php contains a dropdown list and I have included this page in my main.php.

What I want to do is when someone select an option in my dropdown, there should be an alert box indicating my selected item.

main.php

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      //some elements
      <?php include 'combo.php';?>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

combo.php

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form>
      //some elements
      <select name="combo">
        <option value="1">America</option>
        <option value="2">England</option>
        <option value="3">India</option>
        <option value="4">Japan</option>
      </select>
      //some elements
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't do any changes to my combo.php. 
onChange event and the script should be in my main.php. 
I have no idea how to do this, and I don't no whether this is even possible. 
Any help regarding the matter would be highly appreciated.
Thanx.

Comment: You have to take a look at `JAVASCRIPT`. Depend on the construction of your combo, you will be able to add listener on the "change" event on your combo and alert the user or anything else. The Javascript code can be on the `main.php`, because on the client side, there is not any difference between `combo.php` or `main.php`. The client receive a unique generated file wich contain HTML code and possibly Javascript code.

Comment: I did something like this to my combo.php

Comment: <select name="combo" onchange="optionsAlertone(this.value)">

Comment: And call it in my main.php

Comment: function optionsAlertone(aaa)
 {
 
 $abc = aaa;
 
       alert(' You have selected Category : '+$abc);
    }
</script>

Comment: Yes. but where is the function `optionsAlertone` ? You should now write in your `main.php` something like `<script>function optionsAlertone(value) { alert("you have selected : " + value); }</script>`

Comment: yes I did. But my lecture said I can't add onchange="optionsAlertone(this.value)" on my combo.php.

Comment: Means I cant add anything to it.

Comment: So, you can add a listener from the Javascript code inside `main.php` assuming that your combo has a name, id or classname (something that allow you to retrieve it). Take a look at jQuery wich is a good JS library and will help you to do your stuff

Comment: take a look at my response. and mark your best answer if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, you just have to add some piece of code in your `main.php`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#idOfYourSelect").change(function(changeEvent) {
        alert("Your value : " + $(this).val());
    });

});
```

Assuming your `<select>` has at least an id `idOfYourSelect` (or a name, or a css classname - somthing that will allow you to retrieve it from the javascript code)

This will add a listener on the `change` event and run the callback at each time you change the value.

If you can't use jQuery, that will be a little more complicated, you have to play with browser differences, and use `addEventLister` or `attachEvent` to add your listener.

[attachEvent documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (for old IE)

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.addEventListener) for Firefox, webkit, etc

I recommend you to use jQuery, which will handle all these differences for you.

Comment: yes I can use jQuery. Can I add it to my main.php or do I need a separate file? I'm sorry but I really don't know how.

Comment: You just have to add jQuery script by adding a `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` tag in the `<head>` of your HTML document (if the `main.php` contain the `<head>` tag, so, yes this is in the `main.php`). Then, add the code I posted in order to add a listener on your `<select>`.

Answer (score 3):

You may use Jquery for this, for that you have to include this script,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#getSelect").change(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

});
</script>
```

where getSelect is id of select control.

after that add below php code.

```
<form>
      //some elements
      <select name="combo" id="getSelect" onChange="return getSelect(this.value)">
        <option value="1">America</option>
        <option value="2">England</option>
        <option value="3">India</option>
        <option value="4">Japan</option>
      </select>
      //some elements
   </form>
```

Comment: If you're setting the event handler using jQuery you shouldn't be including `onChange="..."` on the `<select>` tag.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist , thanks for response but i dont know why cant we use that? its working properly. can you please explain?

Comment: @YadavChetan You *can* use it, you just don't *need* to. The jQuery part makes the `onchange` attribute in the HTML unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Add a javascript function like this :

```
function getValue(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

And in your dropdown add this function on onChange Property like this

```
<select name="combo" onchange="getValue(this.value);">
    <option value="1">America</option>
    <option value="2">England</option>
    <option value="3">India</option>
    <option value="4">Japan</option>
</select>
```

When you change values of dropdown you should see the values in alert box.

Comment: The combo.php cannot be changed :p

Comment: But my lecture said I cannot modify my combo.php like this onchange="getValue(this.value);"

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: where do I have to add this code? In my main.php right. I know this might be a foolish question. But I'm really new to this and I'm so lost in it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay if you can't change that then if you use JQuery you can add like this

```
$('select[name*="combo"]').change(function() {
      var str = $('select[name*="combo"]').val();
      alert (str);

  });
```

Add this in $(document).ready(function)

Comment: thanx. I finally did it. :)